# Error in preloadImages() function

Tags: jquery

I have this javascript function to preload images:

```
function preloadImages() {
    var images = [];

    function preload() {
        for(var i = 0; i < preload.arguments.list; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image();
            images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
        }
    }

    preload(
        "../img/innovation_1_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_2_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_3_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_4_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_5_hover.jpg"
    );
}
preloadImages();
```

but I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.

[image]

What's wrong? How can I fix it? For reference, I use Chrome.

Comment: replace .list with .length

Comment: with `.length` the error stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

replace your

```
preload.arguments.list
```

with

```
arguments.length
```

```
function preloadImages() 
{
    var images = [];
    function preload() 
    {

        for(var i = 0; i <arguments.length; i++) 
        {

            images[i] = new Image();
            images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
            console.log(images[i]); // for testing
        }
    }
    preload(
        "../img/innovation_1_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_2_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_3_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_4_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_5_hover.jpg"
    );
}
 preloadImages();
```

Comment: In this case I get the same  error in the new place http://i.imgur.com/5bNsFAJ.png

Comment: but it sems it works if I write `images[i].src = arguments[i];` instead of `images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This** `preload.arguments.length` is valid code

```
function preloadImages() {
    var images = [];

    function preload() {
        for(var i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image();
            images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
        }
    }

    preload(
        "../img/innovation_1_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_2_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_3_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_4_hover.jpg",
        "../img/innovation_5_hover.jpg"
    );
}
preloadImages();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could also try this..**

```
function preloader() {
    if (document.images) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();

        img1.src = "../img/innovation_1_hover.jpg";
        img2.src = "../img/innovation_2_hover.jpg";
        img3.src = "../img/innovation_3_hover.jpg";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
```